# Php curl работа с текстом

Tags: php

Через curl php приходит текст, но почему то я с ним никак не могу работать, не регулярки, не explode и другие функции со строками, единственное что можно это вывести его в браузер ( видно все html теги и текст ) но обработать этот текст никак нельзя, при любой попытки деление этого текста белая страница

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, пример входящего текста и то, как Вы пробовали с ним работать.

Comment: Почитайте про работу с DOM в PHP и сразу ответите на все свои вопросы, а так же облегчите себе получение целевого текста из входящей строки. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php https://www.php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.loadhtml.php https://www.php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php